# Change response to only respond one set of values

Tags: asp-classic

I am very novice at asp. Here is my code:

```
response.write("<script>")
dim counter: counter = 0
do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
    counter = counter + 1
    response.write "var CC" & counter & "=" & x.value & ";"
  next
  rs.MoveNext
loop
response.write("</script>")
```

This currently returns both columns from my DB:

```
<script>var CC1=ALFKI;var CC2=13579;var CC3=ALFKI;var CC4=246;</script>
```

I only want the second column to return, which is the numbers (13579 & 246). 
What should I change?

Comment: So you have asked two questions on the same bit of code in the space of a hour, when do you plan and doing some research yourself instead of using SO like your personal code monkey? This is not what the SO community is here for.

Comment: @Lankymart They are simple questions that will get someone who is knowledgeable and willing to help me out some extra SO points. Didn't think it was that big of a deal.

Comment: Just to clarify it's not a personal attack but saying something like *"They are simple questions that will get someone who is knowledgeable and willing to help me out some extra SO points. Didn't think it was that big of a deal"*, is partly what is wrong with SO at the moment and people are noticing it. Just jump over to [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) and see if you have the same opinion after.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253609/limiting-dropdown-options-based-on-userid was my original, detailed, researched and discussed question. I had two small questions remaining after figuring everything out form my previous question, so I figured it best to start new questions as opposed to editing my original question away from its original points. Maybe that's the wrong way to go about it and I apologize for that. You could of passed over these questions if you did not like them, however you still provided insight and answers and I am thankful to you for them.

Comment: No need to apologised, to be honest I was a bit harsh. Maybe next time, add to your existing question might be a better way to go. But honestly I'm no expect on what's right and wrong when it comes to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not sure I should be answering this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683611/change-response-to-only-respond-one-set-of-values/23695426#comment36400499_23683611), but to loop and only [write out on the even iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683611/change-response-to-only-respond-one-set-of-values#comment36389251_23684057) use `Mod()` to test the remainder.

```vb
response.write("<script>")
dim counter: counter = 0
do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
    counter = counter + 1
    'Use Mod() to check counter is even
    If counter Mod 2 = 0 Then response.write "var CC" & counter & "=" & x.value & ";"
  next
  rs.MoveNext
loop
response.write("</script>")
```

---

**Useful links**

- [The Magical Mod Function](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19315/The-Magical-Mod-Function.htm)

Comment: @Brett `Mod()` is a powerful little function. Use it a lot for building rows off specific number of cells dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Ad an IF statement, based on your counter.

```
for each x in rs.Fields
    counter = counter + 1
    if(counter = 1) then
      response.write "var CC" & counter & "=" & x.value & ";"
    end if
next
```

Comment: This returns '<script>var CC1=ALFKI;</script>'. is there a way to have the if statement run if the number is even? IE- if(counter = even) then ....

Comment: @Brett Use `Mod()` to get check for even field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
response.write("<script>")
dim counter: counter = 0
do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
    counter = counter + 1
    if IsNumeric(x.value) then
        response.write "var CC" & counter & "=" & x.value & ";"
    end if
  next
  rs.MoveNext
loop
response.write("</script>")
```

The trick is to check `"If IsNumeric"` then do what you want.