# splitting a string in chunks using classic asp

Tags: vbscript, split, asp-classic, chunks

i got a list coma separated values (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,....) 
i wish to split them into chunks of 5 like (a,b,c,d,e) (f,g,h,i,j).... 
can someone help me with the code in classic asp ?

```
arr = Split(messto, ",") ' convert to array
totalemails = UBound(arr) ' total number of emails

if totalemails mod 5 = 0 then
    totalloops = int(totalemails/5) 
    else
    totalloops = int(totalemails/5) + 1
end if

x = 0 
y = 0
b = 0
for x = 0 to totalloops  


    for counter = (5* x)  to ((b+5)-1)
        if Trim(arr(counter)) <> "" and isnull(trim(arr(counter))) = false then 

        response.Write(Trim(arr(counter)))
        response.Write(counter & "<br>")
        mymssto =  mymssto & Trim(arr(counter)) & ","
        response.Write(mymssto)

        end if  

    next
```

Comment: Use the [Magical `Mod()` Function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23695426/692942)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`Mod()`](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19315/The-Magical-Mod-Function.htm) to do this it's very powerful and underutilised function.

Here is a simple example based on the code in the question;

```
<%
Dim mumberToGroupBy: numberToGroupBy = 5
Dim index, counter, arr, messto

messto = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q"
arr = Split(messto, ",") ' convert to array

For counter = 0 To UBound(arr)
  'Can't divide by 0 so we need to make sure our counter is 1 based.
  index = counter + 1
  Call Response.Write(Trim(arr(counter)))
  'Do we have any remainder in the current grouping?
  If index Mod numberToGroupBy = 0 Then Response.Write("<br>")
Next
%>
```

Output:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pq
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: Change response to only respond one set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695426/692942) *(details the use of `Mod()`)*