# Split int array in to two arrays even and odd VBscript error

Tags: vbscript

I have written code for an array of numbers which prints out. I'm now writing code to split the array into even and off numbers. I've started off with an if statement to separate the numbers but i'm struggling to find a solution on how to do it. My code below is failing as it's unable to split the numbers.

```
Sub main()
    a=Array(5,10,15,20)
for each x in a
    Msgbox(x)

    If MyArray(I) / 2 = MyArray(I) 
        List1.AddItem MyArray(I) ' Even Integers
    Else
        List2.AddItem MyArray(I) ' Odd Integers
    End if
next


End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Mod()` - [Change response to only respond one set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695426)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lankymart suggests, the simplest approach would be to use `Mod()` and check if the remainder is 1 or 0, but you can also do it with the approach you seemed to be working towards:

```
If MyArray(index)/2 = Int(MyArray(index)/2) Then
    ' Even number
Else
    ' Odd number
End If
```

`Mod()` approach:

```
If MyArray(index) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    ' Even number
Else
    ' Odd number
End If
```

Here's a complete subroutine that demonstrates what you are trying to do:

```
Dim arr(4) As Integer
Dim arrEven() As Integer
Dim iEvenValues As Integer
Dim arrOdd() As Integer
Dim iOddValues As Integer
Dim iCounter As Integer

' Initialize array
arr(0) = 5
arr(1) = 10
arr(2) = 15
arr(3) = 20

For iCounter = 1 To UBound(arr)

    If arr(iCounter - 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
        iEvenValues = iEvenValues + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrEven(iEvenValues)
        arrEven(iEvenValues - 1) = arr(iCounter - 1)
    Else
        iOddValues = iOddValues + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrOdd(iOddValues)
        arrOdd(iOddValues - 1) = arr(iCounter - 1)
    End If
Next

Dim sValues As String
sValues = "Even values (" & iEvenValues & "):"
For iCounter = 1 To UBound(arrEven)
    sValues = sValues & " " & arrEven(iCounter - 1)
Next

MsgBox sValues

sValues = "Odd values (" & iOddValues & "):"
For iCounter = 1 To UBound(arrOdd)
    sValues = sValues & " " & arrOdd(iCounter - 1)
Next

MsgBox sValues
```

Comment: How would it fit in with my array though thats where im confused. This is my code so far a=Array(5,10,15,20)
for each x in a
    Msgbox(x)
If MyArray(a)/2 = Int(MyArray(a)/2) Then
    ' Even number
Else
    ' Odd number
End If
next

Comment: I  get a mismatch error when i pass my array though the loop

Comment: For i = Array(5,10,15,20)
    If i mod 2 = 1 Then
        Msgbox(i & " is odd.<br>")
    Else
 
        Msgbox(i & " is even.<br>")
    End If   I'm unable to pass my array through